# Is it possible to store a ddev snapshot in a different place?

Tags: snapshot, ddev

Looking the docs and the web, I didn't find an answer for that. I would like to change by default the place where the ddev snapshots are stored without a symlink to a different folder.

Is that possible in any way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to be able to do that. Although snapshots are simple tarballs, and they can be copied around and used various ways, you can't store them somewhere else because they need to be mounted into the same mountpoint inside the db container.

What you *can* do is store a bunch of snapshots somewhere else and copy one or more into ~/.ddev/db_snapshots as a pre-start exec hook, and they'll then be available for restores.

If you could say more about what you're trying to accomplish I could probably help more.

You may want to look at [Speed up developer onboarding with DDEV snapshots from your CI](https://mglaman.dev/blog/using-ddev-snapshots-speed-github-actions-workflows), which talks about moving snapshots around and storing them.

Comment: Thanks to the answer and to confirm my suspicion. The initial ideia is to have only one place to make backups from there into my storage. I already made a bash script to do the snapshots every day and copy to a different place but, if I have such option, will one step less in my script. You know, lazy people ;)